# Using reRender in visualforce commandbutton after the removal of JS alert/confim

Tags: visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component, ajax

We're trying to change some *confirm()* in a Visualforce Page form due to the deprecation of the alert(), confirm(), and prompt() APIs when used in a third-party context.

We're trying to use the solution proposed here: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/01/preparing-your-components-for-the-removal-of-alert-confirm-prompt

However, the new *Dialog.confirm()* method, works a bit different from the previous *confirm()* and forces us to implement a Javascript function to submit forms.

From what I understand, if we have something like this as the cancel button in a form:

```
...
<apex:commandButton action="{!myAction}" value="{!$Label.Cancel}" rendered="{!renderedVar}" id="btnCancel" reRender="theForm" onclick="if(!confirm('{!$Label.ConfirmCancel}'))return;"/>
...
```

I need to change it like this:

```
...
<apex:commandButton action="{!myAction}" value="{!$Label.Cancel}" rendered="{!renderedVar}" id="btnCancel" onclick="event.preventDefault(); Dialog.confirm('Are you sure?', {ok: 'OK', cancel: 'Cancel'},(ret) => { if (ret) submitData(this); })" reRender="theForm"/>
...
function submitData(theButton) {
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', theButton.id);
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', theButton.value);
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    theButton.form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
    theButton.form.submit();
}
```

Now, the problems are:

1. If we keep the reRender tag in the commandButton it will *refresh* the form meanwhile the dialog is open for the user, so it doesn't *wait* for the user input like the previous confirm() did.
2. If we remove the reRender tag the submit implemented will refresh the entire page, instead of the single form, changing the previous behavior where only the form would be restored.

Is there a way to keep the old behavior? I didn't find any solution to refresh a single form from JS instead using the sub